# How can I change Content-Type in outlook 2013?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I'm using **web based** outlook 2013 and I want to change the content-type form 'multipart/alternative' to 'text/plain' because some mailing list forbid the first choice.

> fatal: Sorry, I don't accept messages of MIME Content-Type
>   'multipart/alternative' (#5.2.3). Sorry, for security reasons this list
>   only accepts plain text email and no large attachments. Please
>   configure your mail client accordingly

So, any ideas about how to change the content-type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are logged into Outlook.com, create an email. At the top there is an `Option` button. Click that and choose `plain text`.

[image]

There is not an option to always have Outlook.com do this, so you will have to change it manually for those messages you want in palin text.

Comment: thanks alot it worked, I will mark the question as answered Now

Comment: But that only allows it to be set to `text/plain`, not an arbitrary MIME-Type.